# What is a good one word theme instead of "Treasured memories"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a good one word theme instead of "Treasured memories" ?

Comment: Please add a sentence to show how you want to use this new word.

Comment: @Ubihatt Answer? This is a question.

Comment: @David oh yeah!  my mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

When you think about precious times in the past, you may be feeling *nostalgic*.

> **nostalgia** [näˈstaljə, nəˈstaljə]
>
> NOUN
>
> a sentimental longing or wistful affection for the past,
>   typically for a period or place with happy personal associations. "I
>   was overcome with acute nostalgia for my days in college"

([oxford dictionaries online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nostalgia))

Alternately, one can *reminisce* about good things that happened.

> **reminiscence** [ˌreməˈnisəns]
>
> NOUN
>
> a story told about a past event remembered by the narrator. "his
>   reminiscences of his early days in Washington"
>
> enjoyable recollection of past events. "his story made me smile in
>   reminiscence"

([oxford dictionaries online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reminiscence))

Comment: Hi Meg, I've edited to include the links for proper citation. Feel free to roll back if you want.

Comment: Nope, that's what I was trying to do!